# Generate approximately semi-orthogonal tall matrix approximately satisfying constraints

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a set of matrices $\{(A_i,D_i)\}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, where:

- Each $D_j\in\mathbb{R}^{S\times S}$ is diagonal, and every entry on the main diagonal is non-negative.
- Each $A_j\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is symmetric and positive definite, with every entry being non-negative.

I want to find a matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times S}$ such that:
$$
A_i \approx B D_i B^T \;\;\;\forall\;\;\;1\leq i \leq n \\
B^TB\approx I
$$
However, everything is noisy (meaning $A_i$ and $D_i$ always have some random perturbation). This means (I assume) that I need something like:
$$
B^* = \arg\min_B \;\alpha||B^TB - I|| + \beta\sum_{i=1}^n || A_i - BD_iB^T||
$$
for some matrix norm (e.g. Frobenius) and (hyper-)parameters $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. I am not too picky about the exact formulation, however, so feel free to tweak it. For instance, perhaps there is a way to make the orthogonality a hard constraint.

My question: how do I solve an optimization problem like the one above?

What have I tried: well, this reminds me of an eigenvalue decomposition problem (if $n=1$ especially), but I have a set of problems I'd like to simultaneously satisfy.
One odd thing though is that the $D_j$ are *known*, or at least estimated (albeit *with noise*). My first thought was to rearrange this into a linear system somehow, but I have not been able to do so (so far).

If there is some literature I can look into relating to this problem, that would be a more than good enough answer. My apologies for the lack of optimization/numerical linear algebra knowledge.

---

Note: I have [posted this to SciComp SE as well](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/generate-approximately-semi-orthogonal-tall-matrix-approximately-satisfying-cons).

Comment: That you write is non-sense except if $S=m$. Indeed, $B^TB\approx I$ implies that $B^TB$ is invertible and $S\leq m$. $A_i\approx BD_iB^T$ and $A_i>0$ implies that $BD_iB^T$ is invertible and $m\leq S$. On the other hand, your formulae imply that $A_iA_j\approx A_jA_i$, what you need to add in the above assumptions.

Comment: @loupblanc All the action is at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29781/20417